# TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice', wh

Tags: python, csv

I've had a problem with my code.

```
def explore_data(dataset, header, start, end, rows_and_columns=False):
    dataset_new = dataset[start:end]    
    for row in dataset_new:
        print(row)
        print('\n') # adds a new (empty) line after each row

        if len(row) != len(header):
            print(row)
            print(dataset_new.index(row))

    if rows_and_columns:
        print('Number of rows:', len(dataset))
        print('Number of columns:', len(dataset[0]))

print(explore_data(ios_text, ios_header, 0, 3, True))
```

The result just giving "None". Any suggestions? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Which problem are you asking about? A TypeError, or your function returning `None`?

Comment: Just to note: you don't return anything from `explore_data`...

Comment: You have not supplied enough code to reproduce the problem. I suspect `ios_text` is a set which would explain the problem.

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question?

Comment: First of all, im so sorry that the code was incomplete. If you wanna see the whole code, you can search it at here: https://github.com/kevkn2/error-helpme/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

In Python a function without a `return` statement returns `None` by default. As a consequence, the last call to `print` will print `None`